# Facebook Site URL?

Tags: facebook

I Recieve this error when I am working with an app I am creating:

> Error
>
> You have specified an App Domain but have not specified a Site URL or a Mobile Web URL
>
> yoursite.com must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL.

Where do I specify the Site URL? I cannot find it anywhere.

Give detailed instructions as FB can be a pain to find things.

There is supposed to be a website tab, where?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Menu choices in FB]

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There is a tab called Website. Just put URL int here. Hope it helps

Updated as of 29/05/2012:

It is now called 'Website with Facebook Login'

Updated as of 17/7/2014:

On Settings > Basic
Click on "Add Platorm"
Then select "Website"
Enter URL(s) in the form that appears

Comment: Where? I edited my question and added a screenshot of the tabs to the left, I see no place for a website.

Comment: On Basic, on the center of the page, scroll down.

Comment: It's the first option under 'Select how your app integrates with Facebook', on the Basic settings page.

Comment: Thanks got it, the Facebook UI is horrible and some of the information is not clear in any way.

Comment: On Facebook, the tab is now labeled as "Website with Facebook Login" rather than just "Website". (which is even more confusing, because I'm making a mobile app, not a website that integrates with Facebook... but they want it entered there anyways)

Comment: Right now you have to check "Website with Facebook Login" for that Input to appear.

Comment: It doesn't *seem* to matter at the moment if you don't actually have a "Website with Facebook Login" at the end of the "Website with Facebook Login" URL, luckily. Hopefully that won't change. God, this stuff is confusing and twisty...

Comment: Poor UI design by FB - the tab appeared to me as only 'tick-able' *CheckBox*

Comment: as of this post the `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` has now been moved to the advance section

Answer (score 13):

You're right.  Facebook apps can be daunting at times.   This is what the problem is:

The Site URL specifies where the facebook app page redirects to, while the App Domain is used for Authentication (such as login feature, etc).

You are specifying as your App Domain (some-other-domain.com) is a different base URL from your Website >> Site URL (yoursite.com/myfacebookapp).

Use the same for both:

- App Domain:: yoursite.com
- Site Url:: yoursite.com/myfacebookapp

The App Domain is typically located in the top under the 
-Your App Settings >> Basic >> Basic Info.

The Website: Site URL is currently located in 
-Your App Settings >> Basic >>"How your app integrates with Facebook">> Website >> Site URL.

:: Set the Site URL you want the page to redirect to, then, if you would like authentication services for that page, include root domain of your Site URL in the App Domain Section.  You are not required to include something in the App Domain section if you do not want Authentication.

Answer (score 12):

[image: This how to register your facebook application]

This how to register your facebook application

Comment: this is the correct answer. why would you select the other one

Answer (score 5):

The current process
Settings Page -> Basic Settings -> Add Platform -> Website
Enter the required url in the Site Url field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tab called "Website with Facebook Login" in "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" box. This is under the Basic info container. Paste your full URL there, like e.g. "http://www.example.com/"

Answer (score 0):

Under apps > settings > website 
enter the URL of your website.